# Execute test cases in a pre-defined order

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Is there a way to execute test cases in GoLang in a pre-defined order.

P.S: I am writing test cases for life cycle of a event. So I have different api's for all the CURD operations. I want to run these test cases in a particular order as only if an event is created it can be destroyed.

Also can I get some value from one test case and pass it as input to another. (example:- To test the delete event api, I need a event_id which i get when I call create_event test case)

I am new to GoLang, can someone please guide me through.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do it is to encapsulate all your tests into one test function, that calls sub-functions in the right order and with the right context, and pass the `testing.T` pointer to each so they can fail. The down-side is that they will all appear as one test. But in fact that is the case - tests are stateless as far as the testing framework is concerned, and each function is a separate test case.

Note that although the tests may run in the order they are written in, I found no documentation stating that this is actually a contract of some sort. So even though you can write them in order and keep the state as external global variables - that's not recommended.

The only flexibility the framework gives you since go 1.4 is the TestMain method that lets you run before/after steps, or setup/teardown:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

    if err := setUp(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rc := m.Run()
    tearDown()
    os.Exit(rc)
}
```

But that won't give you what you want. The only way to do that safely is to do something like:

```
// this is the whole stateful sequence of tests - to the testing framework it's just one case
func TestWrapper(t *testing.T) {

   // let's say you pass context as some containing struct
   ctx := new(context)
   test1(t, ctx)
   test2(t, ctx)
   ...
}

// this holds context between methods
type context struct {   
    eventId string
}

func test1(t *testing.T, c *context) {
   // do your thing, and you can manipulate the context
   c.eventId = "something"
} 

func test2(t *testing.T, c *context) {
   // do your thing, and you can manipulate the context
   doSomethingWith(c.eventId)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you also explain why keeping the state as external global variable is not recommended.

Comment: @VikasVerma you can do it for sure, but from my experience, it's just asking for trouble. what if you run parallel tests, for example? It's better to pass the context between stateless functions.